# Declaring generic type mid-class (not in header) in java, possibly through GenericType class

Tags: java, oop, generics

Basically I have a `class PA<E> extends ArrayList<E>`

This class creates a numerical code (using any subclass of Number) for the instance of type E, and uses said numerical code to keep the ArrayList sorted when more elements are added/removed. It has some default encryption (creating a paired numerical code) functions, but allows programmers to input their own encryption function using lambda if needed. It should be noted that this is gonna be part of a "library" for other programmers to use... its not a stand alone software.

The issue is that some methods/data structures in the PA class have a return type and/or parameter specific to the instance of the subclass of Number being used, and I can't figure out a way to keep this variable type the same. Essentially I'm trying to do something like this:

```java
class PA<E> extends ArrayList<E>{
    final GenType N; //GenType class does not exist to my knowledege. This is what I'm looking for.
    final Function encrypt;
    ArrayList numList;
    Hashtable numTable;
    public PA<E>(E ... elements){
        EncryptAndType ent = defaultENT(elements[0]);
        PA<E>(ent.e, ent.n, elements);
    }
    public PA<E>(Function e; Class n, E ... elements){
        encrypt = e;
        N = new GenType(n); // <-- initializing code-defined-generic
        numList = new ArrayList<N>(); // <-- ArrayList with code-defined-generic
        numTable = new Hashtable<N, E>(); // <-- Hashtable with code-defined-generic
        for(E i : elements){
            N enc = encypt.apply(i); // <-- variables of code-defined-generic type
            if(size()==0) {
                super.add(i);
                numList.add(enc);
                numTable.put(enc, i);
                continue;
            }
            //insert by sorting... code not shown
        }
    }
    public N getNum(E el){ // method returning code-defined-generic type
        return encrypt.apply(el);
    }
    public EncryptAndType defaultENT(E e0){
        if(e0 instanceof Number) return new EncryptAndType(new Function<E,E.getClass()>( e -> e ), E.getClass());
        if(e0 instanceof Character) return new EncryptAndType(new Function<E,Integer>( e -> Integer.parseInt(e) ), Integer);
        //etc... other defaults not shown.
    }

}
class EncryptAndType {
    final Function e;
    final Class n;
    public EncryptAndType(Function f, Class t){
        e = f; 
        n = t;
    } 
}
```

I found this [Class GenericType<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericType.html#getType--) on JavaDocs that says

> "Represents a generic message entity type T. Supports in-line instantiation of objects that represent generic types with actual type parameters. An object that represents any parameterized type may be obtained by sub-classing GenericType. Alternatively, an object representing a concrete parameterized type can be created using a GenericType(java.lang.reflect.Type) and manually specifying the actual (parameterized) type."

I think this can be used, but the JavaDocs doesn't give me any idea how to implement it and I cannot find any articles/tutorials online. I believe it should be similar to the code I provided above but am not entirely sure.

Here are some other solutions I've already thought of but believe would be suboptimal:

1. instead of N use Wildcards, Number class or Object class

This defeats the whole purpose of generics, requires constant casting, makes it irritating to use class specific methods, etc. I'm really against doing this.

2. Two generics for PA (ie `class PA<E,N> extends ArrayList<E>`)

This is suboptimal as the programmer, if using a default encrypt-function, either has to know the return type of the default encrypt-function or has to do `new PA<E,PA.defaultENT().n>` which is doable, but people would constantly forget this & it would be annoying. I'm not 100% against this, but would prefer a better solution if possible.

3. Change `final GenType N;` to `final Class N;` and genericize (is that a word? lol) all methods (ie: `public <N> void methodName`)

It mostly solves the problem with Opt#2, its just that theres gonna be 30ish methods with multiple calls to each other and this would become repetitive, easy to forget and annoying. Again, not 100% against this, but prefer a better solution.

4. Make both constructors private, `PA<E, N extends Number>` and create .new() methods:

```java
public static <E> PA new(Function f, Class c, E ... e){
    return new PA<E,c>(f,c,e);
}
public static <E> PA new(E ... e){
    EncryptAndType ent = defaultENT(elements[0]);
    return new PA<E, ent.c>(ent.e, ent.c, elements);
}
```

I like this the best out of my workarounds so far, the issue is it may be weird for a programmer to not use a constructor to create instances.

Comment: 3 is not actually possible.  2 is as good as it gets.

Comment: @LouisWasserman why wouldn’t 3 work. Seems good to me

Comment: 3 doesn't work because generics don't work that way.  You can't have a Class N and then use N in your generics.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think you misunderstood what I said... when I said "genericize the methods" I mean the method calls as well. So for public <N> N getNum(E e){...} the method call would be PAInstance.<N>getNum(e1); Do you agree that this should work?

Comment: It loses all type safety, because you can't stop your callers from writing `CompletelyUnrelated num = PAInstance.getNum(e1)`, which then throws a `ClassCastException` at runtime.  That makes it...arguably worse than option 1, which will at least tell you that you have to cast and give you the warning that it's unsafe.  Option 3 will just appear to be safe when it's absolutely not.

Comment: @LouisWasserman fair enough, didn't notice that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246502/discussion-between-louis-wasserman-and-ankit).

Comment: This question is a bit odd - the code as pasted in this question isn't java. It has all sorts of syntax errors. Yet, the question isn't about these errors. So, did write out some code just for this question and it's not the actual code that caused the question? That's.. usually a bad idea, best to go with the _actual_ code. It's everywhere - `new` is not a valid method name, `public PA<E>()` is not how you write a constructor, `PA<E>(a, b);` is not how you invoke another constructor, `c` is not legal in `new PA<E,c>`, `ent.c` is even weirder.

Comment: I think you've taken a few steps too far: You're making all sorts of incorrect assumptions about what generics are and how they work, and based on this tower of incorrect assumptions you're asking questions. Perhaps start with making these snippets a basic test project; the cavalcade of errors will help clarify matters. If it it doesn't - all these errors make it really hard to try to give meaningful answers here.

Comment: NB: class `javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType` is a red herring. It will not help here, at all.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I'm not sure if your comment is serious or not... to quote my original post, "Essentially I'm trying to do something like [The example code you are referring to]." I am well aware that you can't put a Class variable to declare a generic type. So yes there will be errors; if I didn't have errors why would I post online asking for help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out an answer to my question... thought I'd post an answer in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

It's similar to idea 4, aka using .create() methods that call private constuctors.

```java
class PA<E , N extends Number>{
    public static <D> PA create(Function enc, D ... elements){
        return create2(enc, elements[0], enc.apply(elements[0]), elements);
    }
    public static <D> PA create(D ... elements){
        Function enc = defaultEncryptor(elements[0]);
        return create2(enc, elements[0], enc.apply(elements[0]), elements);
    } 
    private static <D, M> PA create2(Function f, D eUseless, M nUseless, E ... elements){
        return new PA<D,M>(f, eUseless, nUseless, elements)
    }
    private <E,N>PolyArray(Function f, E eUseless, N nUseless, E ... elements){ 
        // constructor stuff
    }



    public static <D> Function defaultEncryptor(F e0){
        if(e0 instanceof Number) return ( e -> e );
        if(e0 instanceof Character) return ( e -> (Character.getNumericValue((char) e)) );

        //etc... other defaults not shown.
        System.err.println("There is currently no default converter for the number type provided."
                + " This will probably cause errors later in the code."
                + " Use the create(Function encryptor, D... elements) method.");

        return null;
    }


}
```

So basically I use D & M to "initialize" E & N. The programmer doesn't need to put the defaultEncryptedType (aka N) in angle brackets (aka <>) because the create & create2 methods will assume the types from the parameters eUseless & nUseless.